# Migration of Data from Oracle database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, database-migration

> [ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

I don't understand the error message from SSIS. Please I need help.
Thanks

Comment: Read it out aloud to yourself.  It is very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, when the data is converted from `NULL` to DateTime, the `DataTime.MinValue` = 0001-01-01, but in database, the min value is `1/1/1753`, so you have to make some treatments to `NULL`, otherwise when inserting `0001-01-01` (converted from `NULL`), it will throw you that error.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably problem with different date formats on both sides, maybe different language setting for both databases. For example Oracle uses dd-MM-yyyy and SQL expects MM-dd-yyyy. Try to select datetime fields from both databases to check the format. Then try to solve it by some type of conversion in SSIS. You can try converting Oracle date to universal datetime format and then converting back to MS SQL date format. Of course, SSIS should solve it automatically, but working with dates is often buggy and confusing.

The other possibility is, that you are trying to convert TEXT column in Oracle to datetime column in MSSQL and one of the values in the table does not fit expected date format.

Comment: Oracle does not have any format for its date data type - it is stored internally as 7-bytes. It is only when it is converted to a string that a format is applied and Oracle can use any format for this conversion - the default date format is a session parameter (which means any user can change their own default format for that session so two users can have different defaults) and the initial default is also dependent on the territory and language settings of the database. This answer makes many assumptions most of which do not seem to be valid since there is no need to convert dates to strings.

Comment: @MT0, of course, that dates are internally stored as some bytes (7). Migrating dates from Oracle to Oracle can be really simple as copying 7 bytes from one place to aother, I agree with you. But this question is about migrating between Oracle and MSSQL. In such scanario you can not simply move few bytes from MSSQL to Oracle without interpreting content, internal structures are different. At some moment conversion from MSSQL internal structures to Oracle structures MUST occur.